# Camera error on calling the intent. Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I am not sure why I am getting an error.

Camera error
Can't connect to the camera.

Here is my code for the intent (and yes I have the permission in the manifest file)

```
 final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    final String fname = getUniqueImageFilename();
                    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
                    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                    // Camera.
                    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
                    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                        intent.setPackage(packageName);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                        cameraIntents.add(intent);
                    }

                    final Intent chooserCameraIntent = Intent.createChooser(captureIntent, "Use Camera");

                    startActivityForResult(chooserCameraIntent, YOUR_SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
    03-12 00:34:49.038      183-838/? E/mm-camera-intf﹕ mm_camera_open: dev name = /dev/video1, cam_idx = 1
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/mm-camera-intf﹕ mm_camera_open:  opened, break out while loop
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/mm-camera-intf﹕ mm_camera_open: cannot open control fd of '/dev/video1' (Connection timed out)
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/mm-camera-intf﹕ camera_open: mm_camera_open err = -1
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/QCamera3HWI﹕ camera_open failed.
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ Camera 0: initialize: Could not open camera: Unknown error -2147483648 (-2147483648)
    03-12 00:34:54.038      183-838/? E/Camera2ClientBase﹕ initialize: Camera 0: unable to initialize device: Unknown error -2147483648 (-2147483648)
    03-12 00:34:54.048  24562-24562/? E/CameraHolder﹕ fail to connect Camera:-1, aborting.
    03-12 00:34:54.048  24562-24562/? E/CAM_PhotoModule﹕ Failed to open camera:0
03-12 00:36:49.658      768-846/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '434c3678 com.example.app/com.example.app.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-12 00:36:50.048    183-26193/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
03-12 00:36:50.378  24562-24562/? E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.camera.CameraActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42a40b28 V.E..... R....... 0,0-1026,584} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
            at com.android.camera.util.CameraUtil.showErrorAndFinish(CameraUtil.java:357)
            at com.android.camera.CameraActivity$2.onDeviceOpenFailure(CameraActivity.java:247)
            at com.android.camera.AndroidCameraManagerImpl$CameraOpenErrorCallbackForward$2.run(AndroidCameraManagerImpl.java:845)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try rebooting your device. Whatever you are running into is with the camera app and may have nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Thanks that did it... how did that even happen though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a camera app crashes, it can lock up the camera hardware, preventing it from being used again until the device is rebooted. Hence, if you run into "cannot open camera" and similar sorts of messages, try rebooting the device to see if the problem clears up.